# How do I send the contents of a textView as an Email?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, textview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an app that has favorite quotes that are displayed using a textView.  I want to provide the option of emailing directly from this textView. Secondly I would like to be able export to a PDF or Pages document, which I can then email out.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: From the help of SO I went with exporting to PDF.  Pages specification is not yet released by Apple and Word documents are a pain in the butt apparently.  PDFs worked fine and is fast generating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place a UIButton along the textView and send email like this

```
-(void)sendEmail 

{
 

 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 
 [picker setSubject:urSubject];
 
  NSString *emailBody =
 [NSString stringWithString:urTextView.text];
 
 [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];  
 
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
 [picker release];
 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For emailing, you should use MFMailComposerViewController. To export it, you would first require to generate a pdf. And then add it as an attachment to a mail. You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/) on generating pdfs in iPhone. Hope that helps.